# Unable to send control key on IE

Tags: controls, sendkeys

I am using the following command in my code
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL + "v"));

I can see that it is entering "v" in the text box instead of copying the content saved in the variable. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: are you trying to copy or paste? You're saying that you want to copy, but you're trying to send a `CTRL`+`V`

Comment: I have already copied the file to clipboard... want to paste it